# how to load files in TLS PASS Through in Burp Suite?

Tags: burp-suite

I tried to load .txt files in **TLS PASS Through** but it is not accepting the file type. I tried with (.txt) and (.csv) .

The reason behind this is when I open a new project in Burp Suite all time it needs to add manually hosts. So how can I add a list of hosts in a single click?

[image]

Comment: "it is not accepting the file type" -- is there an error? What is actually happening?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Burp does not support wildcard URLs in its Load functionality.

If I load this file:

```
burp_urls.txt
-------------
https://*.google.com
https://portswigger-labs.net
https://example.com
```

Then I get this:

[image: Burp TLS passthrough having only loaded 2 of my 3 URLs]

This is consistent with [this Portswigger Support question from January 2021](https://forum.portswigger.net/thread/advanced-target-scope-load-file-ca92a0b1):

> This sounds like it could be a feature request for the 'Load' option to respect any regex set within the file being uploaded. If possible, can you send the file or an example to us on support@portswigger.net?

So it sounds like if you want this enhancement, then you should email them and request it :)

Answer (score 1):

The only file type you can load is a JSON. Not sure why this isn't clearly stated somewhere, but it took me some time to figure it out. This is the structure of the JSON file:

```
{
    "proxy":{
        "ssl_pass_through":{
            "automatically_add_entries_on_client_ssl_negotiation_failure":false,
            "rules":[
                {
                    "enabled":true,
                    "host":"^*\\.mozilla\\.(com|net|org)$",
                    "protocol":"any"
                },
                {
                    "enabled":true,
                    "host":"^*\\.google\\.com$",
                    "protocol":"any"
                },
               etc..
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The easiest way to create this file is to add the rules through the burp UI and click on the gear icon to save the configuration:

[image: TLS Pass Through Save Options]

This is the process on Burp Suite Professional v2021.4.3, but should be available on any recent version of Burp Suite.